# Указать на activity в классе Application

Tags: java, android, unity3d

У меня есть класс Application, от него наследуются все активити, мне нужно внедрить в него в onCreate рекламу Unity.
Там есть метод Unityads.initialize(Activity, game ID, etc...)
В документации юнити по этому методу указывается this, но мне нужно каким-то образом обойти это, либо указать на активити с которого стартует приложение. Пробовал MainActivity.class, не помогло.. Есть идеи?
Заранее прошу прощение за небольшую непонятность вопроса, тороплюсь

Comment: Поясните что значит * класс Application, от него наследуются все активити*. Если вы так обозвали базовый класс `extends (AppCompat)Activity`, то просто укажите `this` как в документации.

Comment: Нет, я про тот который extends Application. Я точных формулировок не знаю, ещё не доучил джаву и андроид

Comment: Я пробовал добавить инициализации в onActivityStarted(Activity activity) и указать вместо this как раз таки activity, андроид студия ругается мол deprecated

Comment: Тогда про наследие - это не верное выражение. Если требуется текущая активность, то наверно не с проста - делайте инициализацию в каждой активности. Если не охота захламлять код можно сделать базовый класс и от него наследовать все активности или класс помощник, в котором разместить весь код и вызывать его в каждой активности одной строчкой. В принципе можно и в Application, но  в каждой активности дёрнуть его метод инициализации (в смысле ваш метод, который вы там напишете).

Comment: Разместил весь код из документации прямо в новом активити и всё равно пишет depricated. Код абсолютно идентичен тому что в документации..

Comment: Не `Java`, а `JavaScript` (Да, это разные языки)! `Application` есть, но у unity, а не у тебя и что наследуется #%? Куда вставить ? Какой документации? Где ссылка? Переформулируйте вопрос или закройте.

Comment: @Yaroslav, 1) именно Java (на нём пишут для Андроида, если вы не в курсе); 2) речь о другом [`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application). Всё это можно было понять просто прочитав вопрос и комменты. Если вы не в теме или лень вникать - лучше пройти мимо.

Comment: @ДмитрийБорисов, в чём сложность открыть [документацию](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/android/api-android) и увидеть, что методу `initialize` нужно 5 аргументов, а не 4, как в устаревших примерах. Плюс в `JavaDoc`-ах обычно пишут на что нужно заменить deprecated методы

Answer (score 1):

Для тех кто столкнётся с проблемой в будущем, официальная документация юнити по этому вопросу необновлялась уже давным давно и метод initialize  теперь не принимает листнер, можете его смело удалять, обнаружил я упоминание об этом только в описании одного из предыдущих релизов на гитхабе. Т.е. Теперь это выглядит так: UnityAds.initialize(Activity activity, String gameID, Bool testmode) 
@woesss спасибо вам за помощь новичку